# Выборка статей из бд с определенным промежутком времени

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать выборку из бд за определенный промежуток времени.

Есть бд : id,title,text,dt . dt - int в ней хранится время в которое нужно выложить статью на сайт.как мне сделать выборку в промижуток с time() - 1800 до time(). ?

Пробовал SELECT * FROM `t` WEHRE `dt` in(".time() - 1800.",".time().") не то ето. (

Answer (score 1):

если хранится время в юниксах, то

```
WHERE AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( curdate() - interval 1 day )  
AND time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate())
```

Comment: Что даст? Выборка значений за один день ? или что ?

Comment: да, но если заменить interval 1 day на что то свое, то соответственно результат изменится

Comment: Можешь написать что бы выберало значение не по дня а по минутам?

Comment: Спасибо, я так понял в место time поставить свою 'dt' ?

Comment: да.
в моем случае time - это название колонки в таблице, что бы было наглядно ;)

Comment: Не работает  , есть icq или скайп для связи, очень нужна помошь

PS Мне нужно выборку значений например с 20:30 до 21:00

Comment: WHERE dt > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1800